# Libaries correctly extracted?

Tags: java, jersey

A few days ago I switched from the Eclipse IDE to IntelliJ IDE. This is my first time I am coding with IntelliJ. I don't know how I can describe my Problem. :D Where is the Problem? I use this Java Application as a Plugin in my Bungeecord-Proxy

Stacktrace:

> 20:46:16 [WARNING] Exception encountered when loading plugin:
>   CloudNet-RestAPI java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$26.run(WebApplicationImpl.java:1626)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createProxy(WebApplicationImpl.java:1623)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.(WebApplicationImpl.java:335)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl.createWebApplication(WebApplicationProviderImpl.java:55)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:160)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
>     at me.singulativ.restapi.main.RestAPI.onEnable(RestAPI.java:17)     at
>   net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:227)
>     at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:266)    at
>   net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:56)
>     at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl     at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:122)
>     at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
>     at javax.ws.rs.core.EntityTag.(EntityTag.java:35)   ... 24
>   more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl     at
>   net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass0(PluginClassloader.java:53)
>     at
>   net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass(PluginClassloader.java:27)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:62)  at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:155)    at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:105)
>     ... 26 more

Code:

```
package me.singulativ.restapi.main;

import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.Plugin;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RestAPI extends Plugin {

    private HttpServer server;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        try {
            String host = "http://localhost:12345/";
            server = HttpServerFactory.create(host);
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        server.stop(0);
    }
}
```

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFivs.png)

[Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQfL6.png)

Comment: Where did you get that plugin?  How did you attempt to install it?  https://www.spigotmc.org › Forums › BungeeCord › BungeeCord Discussion

Comment: Which plugin do you mean? The problem is not Bungeecord. The Export of the Libaries is the Problem i think.